# enum value being a class, creating an subclass on instantion

Tags: java, list, enums, subclass

I have an enum and on creating an instantion of a class, I want to create object of the class from Enum. Tbh I dont think so that I explained it properly so I will just show it.

```java
public enum TypCiala{
        GWIAZDA,
        PLANETA,
        KSIEZYC,
        ASTEROIDA,
        KOMETA
}
```

```
public Ciało(String nazwa, double okresOrbitowania, TypCiala typ) {
    this.nazwa = nazwa;
    this.okresOrbitowania = okresOrbitowania;
    this.ksiezyce = new HashSet<>();
    this.typ = typ;
}
```

while creating an instantion in Main method I want to create subclass of the typ(my enum) parameter

```
Ciało stack = new Ciało("Earth", 333, Ciało.TypCiala.PLANETA);
```

I have made the subclassed for Enum, but I have no idea how to implement them, so while creating the class there gonna be made subclass of this object

```
public class Planeta extends Ciało{
    public Planeta(String nazwa, double okresOrbitowania, TypCiala typ) {
        super(nazwa, okresOrbitowania, typ);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cleaned up some of your ambiguous code formatting. If not what you intended, edit with further improvements.

Comment: Creating a subclass with the same name as one of the nested enum objects is *very* confusing. I have no idea what you are actually trying to do here. I suggest you rewrite with the simplest possible code, using a contrived example, in English. I’m voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I didnt understand the way of how subclasses work, but now after watching few videos It's more clear to me, I will delete question. Thanks for feedback @BasilBourque

Comment: If you  search Stack Overflow, you will find *many* existing Questions and Answers about using enums in Java.